# We are having different receiver to receive messages from Salesforce Push. Can we cast the same Message received to InboxMessage

Tags: marketing-cloud, push-notification

Any one having idea of how we can form the InboxMessage and pass to method analyticsManager.trackInboxOpenEvent(message as InboxMessage).

Am having an object with message id, alert and title. But when I try to create object of InboxMessage am receiving error as I need to implement method e() of InboxMessage, which am not getting.

Please suggest.

Regards,
Anil

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create an Inbox Message, but this has been solved by a number of customers.  Simply store the message you received in your own database and collate those  messages with the Inbox Messages fetched from `getMessages()` for your display.

Analytics, however, will be a different issue.  Tracking the message being opened will be ignored on our platform as the message does not exist there.

Comment: We are getting empty messages both read and unread. Can we call onMessageReceived from our FirebaseMessaging receiver.

Comment: I think you're doing something very wrong.  Please see https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/javadocs/MarketingCloudSdk/8.0/com.salesforce.marketingcloud.messages.inbox/-inbox-message-manager/index.html